# Stack Overflow Login page layout issue in Opera browser

Tags: support, bug, design, opera

I found a design issue on Stack Overflow's login page. Please check this image:

[image]

I am using Opera 11.60.

**Update:** The layout is also broken in Opera 12.14.

Comment: A page renders incorrectly in Opera?! Well, I'm speechless.

Comment: No repro IE 9.  Lol.

Comment: Same issue with Opera 12.11.

Comment: Reproduced with Opera 12.14 in Windows 7, have to refresh (Ctrl+R) a few times to see the problem. The `input`s with `class=actual-edit-overlay` seems to stay above the text "Sign in with your StackExchange account".

Comment: It's fine on 12.00 though

Comment: @random: Actually it worked in 12.14 just now. However, as Pang already noticed, the error seems to happen randomly.

Comment: With the upcoming change of Opera's internal rendering engine (Presto --> Webkit) I believe this is not really a concern any more.